# Dynamic Number of HTML Dropdowns in Java Struts

Tags: java, html, struts

I have this form on which I would like to create a dynamic number of dropdowns.  I have a list of uncategorized applications which I would like each to have its own dropdown to select its category. I am not sure how to pass the unique data to the server.   The dropdown options will be the same for each.

```
<html:form action="/CategorizeApps.do">
    <h3>Uncategorized</h3>
    <br/>
    Categorize each application using the dropdown menu then click categorize.<br/>
    <table class="list">
        <thead>
            <tr class="controls">
                <td><input type="submit" name="btnAction" value="Categorize"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="fields">
                <td>ID</td>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <logic:iterate id="uncat" name="appsUncat" scope="session">
                <tr class="hlist">
                    <td><bean:write property="id" name="uncat" scope="page"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write property="name" name="uncat" scope="page"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="category" name="category">
                            <logic:iterate id="categories" name="Categories" scope="session">
                                <option value="<bean:write name="categories" property="id" scope="page"/>"><bean:write name="categories" property="name" scope="page"/></option>
                            </logic:iterate>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </logic:iterate>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</html:form>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. The form will send the element you select in the dropdown menú, the form do this by default.... :-?

Comment: each dropdown has to have its own name.  Like AppA, AppB, AppC. But I don't know how many or what the specific names will be.  So my question is that. How do I give each of these unique names and pass them to my getters/setters (also which will need to be dynamically named or make an array).

Comment: Does each application have a unique name or ID that you could append to the dropdown name? Alternatively, can you organize the applications in a indexed collection and append the index number to the dropdown name?

Comment: Yes. Each application has its own unique ID. I could append the ID to the name of the dropdown.  How would I create a getter/setter for each in my CategorizeAppsForm.java ?

Comment: I'm not sure. In .NET I'd probably iterate directly over the form response. It may not matter, but which version of Struts are you using, 1 or 2?

Comment: I am coding in java with struts version 1.3.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once u choose the value then  it will pass to Form(category) and set it in Category. Its done by struts it self. But you should use same Name or Id for value and Option. Or set your drop down value to select value.